# ID Rendering + Diffuse Rendering in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I'm trying to use onBeforeRender to add an id material override function in my THREEjs app. This is a pretty common function for rendering applications, and I'd like to be able to use a scene.overrideMaterial to do it, but from my research it seems like I'm going to roll my own.

My approach is as follows.

When I instantiate objects:

```
...
      m.onBeforeRender = function (){
        if(Renderer._renderID){
            this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(this.userData.idColor.getHex());
            this.material.needsUpdate = true;

            // Attempt at using a shader material
            //this.material = Renderer._idMat;
            //this.material.uniforms.idColor.value = this.userData.idColor;
            //this.material.uniforms.needsUpdate = true;
        }
      }
      m.onAfterRender = function (){
            if(Renderer._renderID){
                this.material = this.userData.material;
            }
      }
...
```

In my render loop:

```
...
        var idTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        Renderer._renderID = true;
        Renderer._renderer.render(Renderer._scene, Renderer._camera, idTarget);
        Renderer._renderID = false;
...
```

Right now the id buffer and diffuse buffer are both rendering with the diffuse material.

Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is needed, I will update this post.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood the question but you really don't want to instantiate a new material every frame in the `onBeforeRender` callback.

Comment: What is your problem, and can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @pailhead One application of this technique is for GPU picking, where you swap out the color being rendered, rather than the entire material definition. That way you only send one instance of the shader code, and simply control the color of each object by changing its uniforms (like in Nick's code that is commented-out).

Comment: Nick, unfortunately, you're correct, you're on your own to implement this. (I've done something similar--it wasn't too difficult once you understand what's happening.) Would it be convenient if three.js provided a first-party implementation? Sure. But three.js isn't an application, it's very much a toolkit, giving you just enough of a wrapper to make things easier, while not being overbearing to your design.

Comment: Thanks Jim - seems like you understand my problem and where I'm trying to get to. Do you think you could give me a hint as to how to achieve this? To my mind (although it's inefficient) my code should be working to render each mesh as a different color. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Did you see the official threejs gpu picking example? @TheJim01 I understand the technique I did not understand the question nor the sequence of events that made one call `new Material()` many times in a frame.

Comment: `and simply control the color of each object by changing its uniforms (like in Nick's code that is commented-out).` @TheJim01 most of three.js works like this. When you have several meshes with `Material` changing `Material.color.set()` changes a uniform, keeps the shader.

Comment: I'll have to put together an example as an answer so I can clarify my points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three.js has an official gpu picking example which can be seen [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html).

They seem to be rendering things in two different scenes and with vertex colors. That's not a bad approach, and i disagree with the comment and your commented out code. Changing the uniforms is not the only way to achieve this, the official example uses vertex colors and merges all the geometries.

There are many ways to skin this cat.

You should by all means avoid creating new materials in tight loops.

This is **suuuuper bad:**

```
  m.onBeforeRender = function (){
    if(Renderer._renderID){
        this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(this.userData.idColor.getHex()); //just a big NO
        this.material.needsUpdate = true; //no it doesnt! it's a new material it has this true by default
```

To achieve something like this, or your own custom override:

```
const myMesh = new Mesh()
myMesh.myMaterials = [
  someRenderMaterial,
  someIDMaterial,
]

scene.traverse(o=>{if(o.myMaterials) o.material = o.myMaterials[1]})
renderer.render(scene,camera)

scene.traverse(o=>{if(o.myMaterials) o.material = o.myMaterials[0]})
renderer.render(scene,camera)
```

But again, there's many many ways to do this. You could just make another scene and render vertex colors. You could make an override material and render vertex colors. Many parameters, many permutations.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the advice! I'll try this out and let you know how it goes!